# Push more than one netbeans project in one repository

Tags: java, git, netbeans, bitbucket

I have a client-server program splited in 3 net beans projects, 1. client 2. server 3. common classes

I would like to push them in one bitbucket git repository but after pushing one of the projects i can't push others

```
Remote Repository Updates
Branch : master
Old Id : dfe16274e865383a78be5ddc294d828650cd73b0
New Id : 855f9f0355e9151330e82948cfda8bfc7a412d65
Result : REJECTED_NONFASTFORWARD

Local Repository Updates
Branch : origin/master
Old Id : null
New Id : 855f9f0355e9151330e82948cfda8bfc7a412d65
Result : NOT_ATTEMPTED
```

Note that there is no package and file name conflicts in these projects.

As looks like there is nothing like/equivalent to `Solution` in Visual Studio to group related projects in net beans, is it a good idea and correct use of git to push all these 3 projects into one repo?

How to push other two projects to my repo?

git version: 1.8.3.1 Net beans version: 7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a single repository from the parent folder. I would suggest that you put the three project folders into a folder lets say: myproject. Then initialize the repository inside myproject and push that to the bitbucket git repository. This way any changes in any of the projects will be pushed to your repository.

Comment: Using this solution can i use net beans GUI to commit and push and etc ?

Comment: Yes you can. You can try it by committing from any project in the repository.